# static block Weird Behaviour

Tags: java, static

```
public class MyClass{
    static{
        System.out.println("Weired Behaviour");
    }
}
```

//If invoked from command line using java MyClass (what and why) would be the output?

Comment: you would have no output because you're missing a main method.

Comment: What do you expect to get? Add more details.

Comment: "*If invoked from command line using java `MyClass` (what and why) would be the output?*" Didn't you try it by yourself? Everything looks simple and obvious. Nothing is weird here.

Answer (score 3):

Output would be:

```
Weired Behaviour
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

It is not Weired actually. Following is the sequence of activities happening in JVM.

When you try to invoke application, the main class is loaded. static block of class gets executed when JVM loads the class - static blocks is kind of class initializer and only gets invoked when class is loaded in memory.

After the class is loaded, JVM tries to find out the entry point - main method. As it does not find main method, exception is thrown.

Comment: BTW I don't see this is [specified behavior](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2). I think it would be just as compatible with the specification for the JVM to determine without loading and initializing the class that the `main` method is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually have something like this, so that it won't yell at you:

```
public class MyClass{

    static{
        System.out.println("Weird Behavior");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){}

}
```

You will see as output:

```
Weird Behavior
```

This is because the static block in the class gets executed when the JVM loads the class.

Answer (score 0):

**Static Initalizer is the block which is executed when JVM loads the class,  before an instance of the class is created, and even before any static method or variable is initialized.**

This will led to the printing of the statement **"Weired Behaviour"**
But then it will try to find the entry point which is **"main" method**, then it will throw an exception. `Exception in thread "main"`